# What is the best way to average a data set that mostly lies in extremes

Tags: distributions, central-tendency

I apologise that the question in the title is a little ambiguous but it is hard to word in a single sentence.

Say I have a set of data, but it is found that a data point is either quite low or quite high, and less likely to be in the middle, imagine the opposite of a normal distribution.

Ie, say I wanted to take a students average grade, but they either were A+, or F. Taking a simple average would give them the same overall score as a straight C student.

What would be the best method for representing some overall score which perhaps could differentiate between those with very split grade profiles, and those with a more consistent one.

Comment: You can have a look at the [Random Sample Consensus algorithm (RANSAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus).
Hope that helps!

Comment: You have to decide whether somebody who is brilliant at some things and useless at others is better or worse overall that somebody else who is generally mediocre but satisfactory.  Statistics cannot tell you this.

Comment: In the specific example of grading, there's another concept in play, which is "don't invent new statistical concepts to grade your students by in the middle of the semester - stick to what you wrote on the syllabus, and if that means you can't tell those students apart then so be it".

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t just report the whole distribution? The average is telling you what it always tells you when it it reports the average as a C; the average is doing exactly what it claims to be doing. // I do not see how RANSAC would help. Loosely speaking, RANSAC would pare away the high and low values, leaving you somewhere in the middle just like the usual mean whose behavior is considered undesirable.